# Multiplication Table For Loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

This is the code I wrote; it's going into an infinite loop and I don't know why..

```
import java.io.*;

public class Multi{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    int num;
    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

    int z,x,y;

    while (num>=1 || num<=11){
        for(z=1; z<=num; z++){
            for(x=1; x<=z; x++){

                y=z*x;

                System.out.print(y+" ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

  }
}
```

The output I want to show in this one is that when a person inputs a number it will display a multiplication table.

e.g.

```
Enter a number: 5

Result:

 - 1 2 3 4 5
 - 2 4 6 8 10
 - 3 6 9 12 15
 - 4 8 12 16 20
 - 5 10 15 20 25

Enter a number: 3

 - 1 2 3
 - 2 4 6
 - 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` condition will never be false:

```
while (num>=1 || num<=11)
```

Every possible number is >= 1 *or* <= 11.  I guess you meant "and" instead of "or".

Also, you need to put the code that sets `num` inside the while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To get a multiplication table for the number get from user 


#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
        
    int i;
    int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
        printf("%d\n",i*num);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code will only produce a *single* row of output. OP is looking for a *table* of numbers.

Comment: Yes as we have added a new line command in it ( \n ) so...  Its not really a table with numbers its maths table means multiplication of a number with numbers within 1-10...